# What is the correct reading of 血泡?

Tags: kanji, readings

As stated in the title - what is the correct reading of 血泡? I couldn't find a definitive answer (Jisho does not know this word at all, Google Translate thinks it should be kehhou, which seems unlikely).
I ran across this in a book and while the translation seems clear ('blood bubbles' or 'bubbles of blood'), I'm not sure about the reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer per-se. I did research into the word and it appears to be Chinese. So the reading in Japanese is a guessing game since it doesn't appear to be an actual Japanese word.

The candidates (including unlikely candidates)

- けっぽう
- けっほう
- けつほう (probably definitely not this)
- ちあわ

Opinion: I would bet on ちあわ for reading it since it would be two separate words in Japanese 血(ち) and 泡(あわ). In this particular case I don't think you'd join the kanji's on-yomi reading rendaku'd or otherwise. Also, typing all 4 spellings into my Japanese keyboard and ちあわ was the only one that came up for a match at all and it was the first match.

Edit: Chocolate said and linked to the fact that けっぽう gives several page hits. けっほう also gives some too. ちあわ also gives a few. This doesn't suggest that any of these answers are right though, just that a group of people were swayed towards one spelling over another.

Comment: Nobody would ever use けっほう... It should be けっぽう

Comment: True, I'll amend my statements. Never heard of a doubled ほ sound before.

Comment: [「けっぽう」とフリガナが打たれているページがいくつか](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22%E8%A1%80%E6%B3%A1%22+%22%E3%81%91%E3%81%A3%E3%81%BD%E3%81%86%22)ありますね。。 [「けっほう」と打たれているもの](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22%E8%A1%80%E6%B3%A1%22+%22%E3%81%91%E3%81%A3%E3%81%BB%E3%81%86%22)も見つかります。。[「ちあわ」も少しですが](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22%E8%A1%80%E6%B3%A1%22+%22%E3%81%A1%E3%81%82%E3%82%8F%22)・・　でも[「けつほう」と打たれている例は見つからない](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22%E8%A1%80%E6%B3%A1%22+%22%E3%81%91%E3%81%A4%E3%81%BB%E3%81%86%22)ですね。。

Comment: Re: geminate (doubled) //h//, it _does_ appear, albeit only in borrowings (AFAIK): see バッハ, for instance, where the geminate //h// is used to approximate the hard German "H" sound or //χ// used to pronounce the final ⟨ch⟩ in _Bach_.